# Find all values of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, contest-math

> Determine all real values of $x$ such that: $$\log_{2}(2^{x-1} + 3^{x+1}) = 2x - \log_{2}(3^x) $$

Let $u = 2^x$ and let $y = 3^x$

**For ease**, let $\log_{2}$ be represented by just $\log$ so:

Then, $\log(u/2 + 3y) = \log(u^2) - \log(y)$, which means, $\log(u/2 + 3y) = \log(u^2/y)$ and so:

$u/2 + 3y = u^2/y \implies \frac{uy}{2} + 3y^2 - u^2 = 0$

Factoring a little, $y(u/4 + 3y) + u(y/4 - u) = 0$ Doesn't help, replace back:

$2^{x-1}3^x + 3^{2x + 1} - 2^{2x} = 0$. But this is all I can go upto? A hint?

Comment: $\log_2\left(2^{x-1}+3^{x+1}\right)=\log_2\left(\frac{2^{2x}}{3^x}\right)$. Let $(u,y)=(2^x,3^x)$, then $\frac{u}{2}+3y=\frac{u^2}{y}$, i.e. $u^2-\frac{uy}{2}-3y^2=0$, i.e. $(u-2y)(u+1.5y)=0$.

Comment: The last equation you get is simply equivalent to $(u-2y)(u+1.5y)=0$.

Comment: More generally, you can always solve $au^2+buy+cy^2=0$ for any real constants $a,b,c$ by using the quadratic formula e.g. $\Delta=(by)^2-4acy^2$; or dividing both sides by $y^2$ and solving the quadratic in terms of $\frac{u}{y}$.

Comment: $u=-1.5y$ is impossible, because $u,y>0$. Therefore $u=2y$, i.e. $2^x=2\cdot 3^x$, i.e. $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}=3$, i.e. $\log_{2/3}(3)=x-1$, which gives the only solution $x=\log_{2/3}(2)$.

Comment: I've solved the whole problem here in the comments; is it still not clear? You asked for a hint: here's the hint: your last equation is simply $(u-2y)(u+1.5y)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Your last equation is simply $(u-2y)(u+1.5y)=0$. Since $u,y>0$, we get $u=2y$. See my comments for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the main idea is to write $2x$ as $$\log_2 2^{2x}$$

Comment: OP used this idea in his work.

Comment: but he wrote it doesn't help